# Translate navigation with LinguaPlone

Tags: plone, linguaplone

I want to translate the navigation part of a plone website with LinguaPlone but it doesn't work (or at least I don't know how to do that).
How can I show the navigation in the correct language whenever the user switches the language?
I have tried to edit the folder in the other language but then both languages have the newly translated navigation entry.
Thanks

Comment: Is the 'Automatically generate tabs'-option in the navigation-controlpanel disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which part of the navigation you mean (tabs, sitemap, etc.)

Plone+LinguaPlone navigation items are picked up by

- By the current active language
- Items which Language is set to "Language neutral"
- Navigation is populated with "Title" of the content from the current language

Site map, top tab bar, etc. navigation portlets should be automatically translated. No special tricks needed, so you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Plone 3.2 is installed and with navigation I mean something like http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-2.5-user-manual/introduction/plone-logged-in.png ("Home", "Members", "News" etc.).

Comment: I think it is not possible to help you further without seeing the site. I suggest you try the latest Plone 4.1 with clean site install, as it is working as intended.